# C++ Conversion to Vector Representation of a Number in Any Base

Tags: c++, vector, numbers, radix, base-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ template for conversion between decimal and arbitrary base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870121/c-template-for-conversion-between-decimal-and-arbitrary-base)

I would like to convert an instance of `unsigned int` to an instance of `std::vector<unsigned int>` in base X where X is any number from 2 to maximum number an `unsigned int` can represent.

**EDIT:** I used to say an `unsigned int` in base 10, but that got critical comments, and I think that's right, so I removed it to avoid confusion.

There are a lot of questions and answers on SO that cover something like `itoa` that converts up to base 16 or 32 or some small number (with [this `itoa` implementation page](http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/~slowe/cpp/itoa.html) being pointed out as good resource). I wasn't able to find a nice conversion for bases much larger than that.

Note: Performance is not a concern (within reason).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “an instance of `unsigned int` in base 10”? `unsigned int`s are usually stored in base 2.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Why don't you write it yourself? There's no standard way to do it.

Comment: "an instance of `unsigned int` in base 10" does not make any sense. The radix is a property of the *representation* of the number, not of the number itself.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You mean on the right ;)

Comment: It's a simple algorithm that I would normally quickly write myself, and if no one answered, I would write it myself for an answer. I was just hoping that there was a nice STL solution that would lend itself to operations on such vector representations.

Comment: @OilCharlesworth No that's limited to base 16 or lower like most of the other answers.

Comment: @LexFridman: Is it?  I don't see any limit in the accepted answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `uint` is stored as binary, but usually they are assigned as decimals, e.g.: `unsigned int x = 37;`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, see how `alphabet` in that answer goes from 0 to I? I (aka 19) is the largest base.

Comment: @LexFridman: Sure, and you can trivially extend that, or modify it to just write the integer values of each digit.

Comment: @Lex That’s irrelevant for the algorithm.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The extension is not trivial in the implementation (see answer). The extension IS trivial in the pseudocode. We are not talking about pseudocode, but actually C++ implementation.

Comment: @LexFridman: All of the answers below are essentially identical to the accepted answer in the linked question...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, and the `char *` and `std::string` implementation of `itoa` are "essentially" the same [on this page](http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/~slowe/cpp/itoa.html) but both are valuable and are presented separately for good reason.

Comment: @LexFridman: I think you're arguing for no good reason.  There's an existing question with the algorithm you're after, and it should be trivial to adapt it to your needs (vector, string, char *, arbitrary base, whatever).  If there's something wrong with that solution, you should edit your question to explain the problem.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Let's agree to disagree. Perhaps you are right in terms of the SO community, but I thought that an STL version of this algorithm has a different implementation and it would be useful for someone searching for such a solution. The fact that both the answers so far are slightly incorrect (`push_front` is not a valid function for `vector` and with `push_back` you have to reverse the `vector`) tells me that the extension is not so trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code converts `x` to a vector in base `base`. It also pad the resulting vector with extra zeros if needed to satisfy `minSize` size of the resulting vector.

```
vector<unsigned int> intToAnyBase(unsigned int x, int base, int minSize = 1) {
    assert(base >= 2);

    // minSize allows us to pad the resulting vector
    // with extra zeros at the front if needed
    minSize = std::max(1, minSize);

    std::vector<unsigned int> v;
    while(x > 0) {
        res.push_back(x % base);
        x /= base;
    }

    // Append zeros to the "front" to satisfy 'minSize' requirement.
    // This also adds support for x
    if(v.size() < minSize) {
        v.reserve(minSize);
        while(v.size() < minSize)
            v.push_back(0);
    }

    std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());

    return v;
}
```

Note that the resulting vector is reversed in the function so that that, for example, decimal 4 produces `{1,0,0}` as a result and not `{0,0,1}`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
std::vector<unsigned int> result;
unsigned int base = ...;
unsigned int input = ...;
while(input) {
  result.push_back(input%base);
  input /= base;
}
```

Comment: if you `push_back` you have to reverse the `result` vector.

Comment: I disagree. If you `push_back()`, then `result[0]` is the ones column, `result[1]` is the 10's column, `result[2]` is the 100's column, etc (assuming base 10, for example). This strikes me as the natural ordering of the vector.

Comment: a decimal like 4 should produce a vector `{1,0,0}` not `{0,0,1}` in base 2.

Comment: If you want a reverse answer, then you'll need to apply `std::reverse`. No big deal.

Comment: Ps. If bigendian storage is a requirement for you, please mention that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<unsigned int> toBaseX(unsigned int number, unsigned int base)
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> res;

    if (number == 0)
    {
        res.push_back(0);
        return res;
    }

    while (number > 0)
    {
        unsigned int currentDigit = number % base;
        res.push_back(currentDigit);
        number /= base;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: `vector` has no `push_front`.

Comment: @Fanael: correct, will fix in a sec.

Comment: Now, with `push_back` you get the result in reverse.

Comment: Also, it should handle `number = 0`

Comment: @Fanael: "reverse" it's just a way of prospective. and actually index [0] holding the LSB seems more intuitive.